# analyzing Windows 7 minidump

Tags: windows-7, drivers, minidumps

I need some help here with analyzing a windows 7 minidump file. with windbg I got this:

### Debugging Details:

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x19_3

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8000340c70f to fffff800032d9bc0

STACK_TEXT:
fffff880`02cfa998 fffff800`0340c70f : 00000000`00000019 00000000`00000003 fffff8a0`13083150 fffff8a0`13083150 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`02cfa9a0 fffff800`0340d4f1 : 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`13a1a000 fffff8a0`13a1a010 00000000`00000ac4 : nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0xcbb
fffff880`02cfaa30 fffff800`032e2e5c : fffff8a0`13a1a030 fffffa80`07c82060 fffffa80`656b6f54 fffffa80`03c6cf30 : nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x411
fffff880`02cfaae0 fffff800`035d11f4 : fffffa80`07c82060 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`07d6e060 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObfDereferenceObject+0xdc
fffff880`02cfab40 fffff800`035d17a4 : 00000000`000009cc fffffa80`07c82060 fffff8a0`0d92ded0 00000000`000009cc : nt!ObpCloseHandleTableEntry+0xc4
fffff880`02cfabd0 fffff800`032d8e53 : fffffa80`07d6e060 fffff880`02cfaca0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObpCloseHandle+0x94
fffff880`02cfac20 00000000`77a613aa : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
00000000`026ce758 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x77a613aa

STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!ExDeferredFreePool+cbb
fffff800`0340c70f cc              int     3

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!ExDeferredFreePool+cbb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  Pool_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  Pool_Corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

IMAGE_VERSION:  6.1.7601.18409

MODULE_NAME: Pool_Corruption

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x19_3_nt!ExDeferredFreePool+cbb

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x19_3_nt!ExDeferredFreePool+cbb

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x19_3_nt!exdeferredfreepool+cbb

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c0c01565-cb93-0237-5ef3-d7ef8da6721e}

Followup: Pool_corruption

---

So all I can see is a driver problem .. but which one?
Since this was my first try analyzing a dmp file with windbg .. here is the dmp file if you can find anything else, plz let me know: [minidump](http://bit.ly/1ujKa3M)
and also the xml file that windows claims to be helpful with identifying the problem (useless for me so far): [xml](http://bit.ly/1usVsT3)

thanks for bothering ;)

Comment: Use something like `BlueScreenViewer` to provide us a list of the drivers loaded into memory when the crash happens.  The supplied information is extremely hard to use to determine that without access to your computer.

Comment: Sometimes this crash happens while booting up, sometimes hours later .. you never know. Isn't BlueScreenViewer for analyzing a minidump? When I use it on the dmp file it marks only ntoskrnl.exe in red.